# How to turn separate year, month and day columns into a single date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a year column that contains things like 2013, 2012, etc. A month column that displays 1-12, and a day column that contains 1-31. I need to run a select that concatenates them and casts them as an actual date, but I am unsure how to go about this. Can anyone provide some input?

Comment: Are the columns numeric of character to start with?

Comment: Also would be great if you tag your question with the exact version of SQL Server you need to support. There are different and better answers depending on the version of SQL Server you're using.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008+:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2)))
```

For SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+
                        RIGHT('00'+CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+
                        RIGHT('00'+CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2)),2))
```

Answer (score 8):

In SQL Server 2012, you will probably be better off avoiding string concatenation or complicated math, as they created a function seemingly just for you:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2013, 8, 19);
```

Of course, storing the data wrong in the first place can lead to problems - for example, what constraint prevents y = 2013, m = 2 and d = 31 from being in the table? You'd think you could wrap that with `TRY_CONVERT()`, but not so much:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATEFROMPARTS(2013, 2, 31));
```

Error:

> Msg 289, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
> Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

So, in order to prevent bad data from getting into these three columns, you will need to use one of the above cumbersome approaches in a check constraint or a trigger...

## ...or...

...in any version, you could fix the table and store a date (or datetime) in the first place. You get all the benefits of automatic validation as well as intrinsic date/time functionality that you don't get with three separate unrelated integers. Much better off pulling the parts out when you need them separately (with computed columns, a view, or at query time) from a value that is guaranteed to be a date, than try to rely on the individual parts to form a valid date...

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT CAST(STR(10000 * Year + 100 * Month + Day) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, I had year and month column in table and i want to check it with start date and end date..So i was looking for solution by using which i can construct date in SQL and check with start and end date...

CAST((10000 * ci.year + 100 * ci.month + 01) AS DATETIME)  >= startDate

Answer (score 0):

One more, just to fill up list of various approaches:

```
select
    dateadd(d, t.d-1, dateadd(m, t.m-1, dateadd(yy, t.y-1900, 0)))
from (values 
        (2011, 10, 26)
        ,(2012, 1, 5)
        ,(2013, 7, 15)
    ) t(y, m, d)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this if your columns are character columns

```
Select Cast([year] + '-' + [month] + '-' + [day] as datetime)
From yourTable
```

If they are numeric you'll need to cast each column to varchar before concatenating otherwise you'll end up getting something funky

Comment: If it works or not depends on server settings. Try `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;SELECT CAST('2012-01-03' AS datetime)` for a surprise

Comment: @adrianm Interesting, why doesn't this affect the `CONVERT` function in the top answer?

Comment: @adrianm but also if I do `SET DATEFORMAT dmy; Select  year(CAST('2012-01-03' AS datetime))` I get 2012 where as I would expect it to return an error or 3?

Comment: Don't know if it affects the top answer. The 2005 version works because it uses the setting independent format yyyyMMdd. 2008 version converts to date which I assume has different defaults than datetime.

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT dmy does not prevent sql server from trying to be clever. It uses DATEFORMAT only when needed (i.e values beween 1 and 31). Another reason to not rely on default behavior in production code.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `Convert` function

```
Select Convert(datetime ,YEAR + '/' + MM + '/' + DAY)
```

Replace `YEAR` with your year column, `MM` with month, and `DAY` with your day column. and concatenate to formulate your date string

Comment: This seems to be for Oracle, but the question is tagged with SQL Server

Comment: I guess the `From dual` is what you were talking about? that might be Oracle but the `Convert` function is an **SQL-Server** function.

Comment: Yes, the `CONVERT` is an SQL Server function, but `YEAR`, and `DAY` are reserved words there, so you can't just use them without enclose them in `[]`. And you are also missing the `CONVERT` format to identifiy that you are passing a date on `YYYY/MM/DD`. Lastly, you are assuming that all the columns are chars, since you are not converting them first. (Oh, I forgot, I hadn't even downvoted your answer in the first place)

Comment: @Lamak as per my explanation I already said replace `YEAR` with his column, same thing with `MM` and `DAY` since they are keywords as you had said, regarding the format, wouldnt that be per your machine/server settings? Anyways your comment was vague so I had to ask :O... And a -2 isnt the problem here so its ok if you downvoted :)