# Create new column based on concatenate three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008, database with one table and these three columns

- [Date of visit Year], float            "2015,2016"
- [Date of visit Month], nvarchar(255)   "June,July,August"
- [Date of visit Day], float             "1,2,3,4"

I am looking at concatenating them into one column that I created called "date of visit" with data type `Date`. This table has about 150000 rows, I checked this link
[How to turn separate year, month and day columns into a single date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323257/how-to-turn-separate-year-month-and-day-columns-into-a-single-date) but it's not working for me

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what kind of error messages are you getting when you try it?  We can help you better if you tell us what it is you've done so far.  See https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the date string as:

```
select [Month] + ' ' + cast(day as varchar(255)) + ', ' +cast([Year] as varchar(255))
```

SQL Server will recognize this as a date format, so you can just convert to a date:

```
select cast([Month] + ' ' + cast(day as varchar(255)) + ', ' +cast([Year] as varchar(255)) as date)
```

Comment: thank you so much for reply, the result like what i want, but i create column in the same table to save the result on it, how can i do that?? thanks

Comment: @HossamAlkhalili . . . In SQL Server, you would add a computed column.

Comment: thanks i appreciate you help