# MySql Selecting Records By Checking Date While In Database There Are Only Integer Fields For Date Instead of Date Formatted Field

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below

```
id        day          month           year       post           title
--        ---          -----           ----       ----           -----
1         11           3               2017       some text      some title
2         12           3               2017       some text      some title
3          3           4               2017       some text      some title
4          1           5               2017       some text      some title
```

What I want to do is I want to select all the records from table from a given date to today date. For example, if the table has a date formatted field, my sql select statement will look like below

```
SELECT * From table Where date_field between '01/01/2015' and curdate()
```

But, I have no date formatted field in my table. There are only integer fields for date in my table. So, I don't know how to select with the condition of between date.

I tried to find the solution for my problem. But I can't find the solution for my problem. I'm a novice php web developer.

So, can any one please solve my problem? Please help me.

Comment: You can use `CONVERT(DATE,CAST([year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST([day] AS VARCHAR(2))) between start and end`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18323293/2630817

Comment: @Justcode Thanks friend. From your suggestion I tried to rewrite my query by surfing Internet. And I found a solution. Here is my solution >>

$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM(
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.day, '/', m.month, '/', m.year),'%d/%m/%Y') AS POST_DATE, m.* FROM `maxim` AS m) as t 
WHERE t.POST_DATE BETWEEN :start_date AND curdate()";

Really thanks you friend. Because I got this solution basically from your concept. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From suggestion of @Justcode I found the solution of my problem. Here is the solution >>>

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.day, '/', m.month, '/',m.year),'%d/%m/%Y') 
        AS POST_DATE, m.* FROM `maxim` AS m) as t 
        WHERE t.POST_DATE BETWEEN :start_date AND curdate() ORDER BY id DESC";

$stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(":start_date", $start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Thanks @Justcode for your concept.