# Conversion of three columns - year, month and day into a single date Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, type-conversion

I have a table that holds date in a different way, three columns, one for year, another for month and one more for day. Because I would like to use date comparisons I need them as a standard single column in date format.
example:

```
 YEAR | MONTH | DAY
+-----+-------+-----+
 2011 | 01    | 01
```

wanted result is to have date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. So far I have searched and found some solutions, but I couldn't make them work - [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323257/how-to-turn-separate-year-month-and-day-columns-into-a-single-date) doesn't work in Oracle, Second is more mathematical solution:

```
select (2011-1900)*10000 +1*100 +1 (date) from dual;
```

Gives error: `ORA-00936: missing expression`

What can I do to achieve the expected result? Might there be another solution without using math?

Comment: Look for TO_DATE function

Comment: What is the datatype of your 3 columns?

Comment: @trincot the datatype is number of all 3

Comment: You should fix that design and store that information directly in a single `DATE`  column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is not my design )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not aim for a date *format*, but for a date *type*. The format is just a way to render such a date on the display, but the date type is easiest to use in date calculations and comparisons.

So, assuming your three columns are string types which always have the padded zeroes as in your example (i.e. January as `01` not `1`), you could do this:

```
select to_date(year || month || day, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual
```

If your columns are numeric:

```
select to_date(to_char(year, 'FM0000') || to_char(month, 'FM00')
            || to_char(day, 'FM00'), 'YYYYMMDD') from dual
```

If you really need the text format calculated directly from the three values:

```
select year || '-' || month || '-' || day from dual
```

And again, if your columns are numeric:

```
select to_char(year, 'FM0000') || '-' || to_char(month, 'FM00')
                               || '-' || to_char(day, 'FM00') from dual
```

Comment: what is the meaning of FM000 FM00? the columns are stored in number data format

Comment: The [documentation for Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) used in `TO_CHAR` - which describes both the `0` format model and the `FM` format model modifier.